# Binary Search for 2D vector

Tags: c++, std, stdvector, binary-search, 2d-vector

I am trying to write code for Binary search program on a 2D vector. I tried code. But I can't understand what is the error I have got. I have given below my code and errors.

```
class BINARY_ON
{
    public:
        explicit BINARY_ON(int column,string fCol) :m_column(column),fColType(fCol) {}

        bool operator()(const string& lhs,const vector<string>& rhs)
        {
               if(fColType=="number")
                      return atoi(lhs.c_str()) < atoi(rhs[m_column].c_str());                   
               else if(fColType=="date")
                      return PPCheckTwoDate(lhs, rhs[m_column])<0;
               else
                      return lhs < rhs[m_column];   
        }
    private:
        int m_column;
        string fColType;
};

int main ()
{
    vector<vector<string>> table_data;

    // Vector Data Insert

    BINARY_ON compare_column(4,"date");

    if (std::binary_search (table_data.begin(), table_data.end(), "01051996", compare_column))
    std::cout << "found!\n"; else std::cout << "not found.\n";
}
```

I got the below errors.

```
>  /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:2416:4: error: no match for call
>  to ‘(PPBINARY_ON) (std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&, const char
>  [9])’ 
> 
> note: bool PPBINARY_ON::operator()(const string&, const
>  std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&) 
> 
> note: no known conversion for
>  argument 1 from ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >’ to ‘const
>  string& {aka const std::basic_string<char>&}’
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the arguements in your operator overload should be reversed.

```
bool operator()(const vector<string>& rhs, const string& lhs)
```

As the compiler is looking for the vector< string > as the first argument

```
>  /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:2416:4: error: no match for call
>  to ‘(PPBINARY_ON) (std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&, const char
>  [9])’
```

Comment: After changing the function definition , i got the below error. 
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h: In function ‘bool std::binary_search(_FIter, _FIter, const _Tp&, _Compare) [with _FIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >*, std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > > >, _Tp = char [9], _Compare = BINARY_ON]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:2714:56: error: no match for call to ‘(BINARY_ON) (const char [9], std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&)’

Comment: In C++ hardcoded strings are arrays of type char. Hence the const char[9]. Convert your "01051996" to a type string before passing it to the binary_search function. You could also change the function definition to use const char[], but that may required code changes to the function.